# Inserting CameraTag <video> tag into a div tag from JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to show a bootstrap modal that shows a video depending on the image that was clicked in a gallery. The problem is that the  tag inside the modal is empty. I'm able to get the id but the embedded player never appears.

I added this to the  tag:

```
<script src='//cameratag.com/api/v5/js/cameratag.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

If I add this line inside the html code it works:

```
<video id='rando' data-uuid='["v-dcxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxx-xxxx-126dea3"]'></video>
```

This is the function I execute:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
            function addVideo(video) {

            document.getElementById("modalContainer").innerHTML = '<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"><div class="modal-dialog" role="document"><div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-header"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button><h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4></div><div class="modal-body" id="videoContent"><video id="rando" data-uuid=\'["' + $(video).attr("id") + '"]\'></video></div><div class="modal-footer"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button></div></div></div></div>';

            $('#myModal').modal('show') 
            }
</script>
```

Help! :)

Comment: Check for any errors in the console first /

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of double quotes.

```
data-uuid=\'["' + video + '"]\'
```

should be

```
data-uuid=\'[' + video + ']\'
```